# Need some help about using SQLite tables (about performance)

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have a database where I store an undefined number of events. I also have an application which reads that database in order to show those events.

In my app people can put comments about that database, so my question is:

Where do I store those comments?

I have thought two ways:

OPTION I -> Create a table for each event and then store that event comments there (could I have problems if too many tables are saved?)

OPTION II -> Create a table for all comments of all events and identify each comment with an Event ID field

I accept any suggestion. I do it all about performance :)

Comment: This is an SQLite question; why did you tag it MySQL?

Comment: Because I don't know what are the differences, I thought they were the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Always use a *single* table for the same type of information.

Use one *Comments* table and refer to the event (Option 2). That table could look like this

```
comments table
--------------
id        int PK auto_increment
event_id  int FK
content   text
```

Comment: So, should I apply 2nd option?

Comment: Why that? Is there a problem on creating too much tables? Thanks!

Comment: It is bad DB design. A DB design should not be changed on runtime. It should be static. If you create tables all the time then there is something wrong. And you would have to create dynamic queries since you have to put the event_id into the table name.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer